# tkinter button function inside of page class

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

class program(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args,**kwargs)

        self.title("Staff Management System")
        self.geometry("1280x720")
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}

        #frame that will hold all the elements
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="nsew")
        container.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        container.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        container.configure(background="blue")

    
        #listing frames (pages) to be controlled
        for F in (homePage, staffLogin):
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        
        self.show_frame(homePage)

    def show_frame(self, page):
        frame = self.frames[page]
        frame.tkraise()

class homePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent,*args, **kwargs)

        

        for i in range(5):
            self.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
        
        for i in range(5):
            self.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)


        promotionsButton = tk.Button(self, text="Promotions", height = 4)
        promotionsButton.grid(row=5, column =0, sticky='w')

        staffLoginButton = tk.Button(self, text="Staff Login", width = 50, height = 20, command= lambda: controller.show_frame(staffLogin))
        staffLoginButton.grid(row=2, column=1)

        managerLoginButton = tk.Button(self, text="Manager Login", width = 50, height = 20)
        managerLoginButton.grid(row=2,column=2)

class staffLogin(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.controller = controller

        for i in range(128):
            self.columnconfigure(i,weight=1)

        for i in range(128):
            self.rowconfigure(i,weight=1)

        self.staffLabel = tk.Label(self, text = "Staff Login", font=("Helvectia", 24))
        self.staffLabel.grid(row = 40, column=60)


        self.userIDLabel = tk.Label(self, text = "UserID:")
        self.userIDLabel.grid(sticky="W", row=67,column=59)

        self.userIDInput = tk.Entry(self, width=50, font=("Helvectia",16))
        self.userIDInput.grid(row=67, column=60)

        self.userPasswordLabel = tk.Label(self, text = "Password:")
        self.userPasswordLabel.grid(sticky="W", row=70, column=59)

        self.userPasswordInput = tk.Entry(self,width=50, font=("Helvectia",16))
        self.userPasswordInput.grid(row=70, column=60)

        self.showPassword = tk.Button(self, text="Show Password", command=self.togglePassword())
        self.showPassword.grid(sticky="W", row=71, column=60)

        self.loginButton = tk.Button(self, text="Login", height=2, width=7)
        self.loginButton.grid(sticky="E",row = 71, column=60)

        self.backButton = tk.Button(self, text="Back To Main Menu", height=4, command= lambda: controller.show_frame(homePage))
        self.backButton.grid(row=128, column=0)
    
    def togglePassword(self):
        if self.userPasswordLabel.cget("show") == "*":
            self.userPasswordLabel.config(show= "")
            self.showPassword.config(text="Hide Password")
        else:
            self.userPasswordLabel.config(show="")
            self.showPassword.config(text="Show Password")

thing = program()
thing.mainloop()
```

im trying to create a function that runs when clicked inside of my "staff login" page. However, due to me using a new method of programming tkinter to be able to switch pages, I am unsure of how to get functions for buttons to work. currently, i get an error saying that the methods that i am trying to call do not exist. im not sure of what to do in order to be able to run functions inside of pages

Comment: Post the full error traceback.

Comment: `command=self.togglePassword`, also you have seemingly mixed up `PasswordLabel` with `PasswordInput` in that method

Comment: @acw1668 `AttributeError: 'staffLogin' object has no attribute 'showPassword'`

Comment: The issue can be fixed by following what @Matiiss said in his comment.